# Smooth 3D spline

Tags: 3d, geometry, spline

REF: [Curve Fitting 3D data set](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/588438/curve-fitting-3d-data-set)

Does anyone know how to construct a **smooth 3D spline** with **3D control points**?

If you look at the reference provided above, the red points will serve as the control points for the spline (which is supposed to be a best-fit representation of the 3D point cloud).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could deconstruct it into 2 2D problems:

1. Split the data along the X and Y
   axes.
2. Form the full 3D equations of
       the splines with all of the unknown
       coefficients.
3. Imagine your data
       projected onto the YZ and XZ planes.
4. In the XZ plane, solve the equations
       for half of the coefficients.
5. Then,
       in the YZ plane, solve for the other
       half.