# 2D non-polynomial function fitting from the command line

Tags: function

I just wrote a simple Unix command line utility that could be implemented a lot more efficiently.  I can measure its performance by just running it on a number of inputs and measuring the time it takes.  This will produce a set of pairs of numbers, s t, where s is the input size and t the processing time.  In order to determine the performance characteristics of my utility, I need to fit a function through these data points.  I can do this manually, but I prefer to be lazy and let a utility do it for me.

Does such a utility exist?

Its input is a sequence of pairs of numbers.
Its output is a formula that expresses how the second number depends as a function on the first, plus an error measure.

One step of the way is to have a utility that does this just for polynomials.
This [has been discussed here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/382186/fitting-polynomials-to-data) but it didn't produce a ready-to-use solution.

The next step is to extend the utility to try non-polynomial terms: negative-degree polynomials (as in y = 1/x) and logarithmic terms (as in y = x log x) will need to be tried as well.  One idea to cope with the non-polynomial terms is to just surround the polynomial fitting with x and y scale transformations.  I don't know whether that will do.  [This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/529184/simple-multidimensional-curve-fitting) is related but not exactly the same.

As I said, I'm lazy: I'm not looking for ideas on how to to write this myself, I'm looking for a reliable result of a project that has already done it for me.  Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2):

I believe that SAS has this, RS/1 has this, I think that Mathematica has this, Execel and most spreadsheets have a primitive form of this and usually there are add-ons available for more advanced forms.  There are lots of Lab analysis and Statistical analysis tools that have stuff like this.

RE., Command Line Tools:

SAS, RS/1 and Minitab were all command line tools 20 years ago when I used them.  I bet at least one of them still has this capability.