# 3D Polynomial Regression

Tags: 3d, regression, polynomial-math

I need some pointers for writing a polynomial regression routine for 3-dimensional points (i.e. find the coefficients of an X order polynomial that is fitted to a certain number of 3D points).

I've found code for 2D polynomial regression, however, I need to account for a 3rd dimension.

I'm looking for code examples and/or explanations.

Comment: take a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/529184/simple-multidimensional-curve-fitting

Comment: You mean fit a 2 dimensional surface of the form z = f(x,y) where f(x,y) is a bivariate polynomial?

Answer (score 0):

The MATLAB function polyfit should readily do it.
http://www.mathworks.de/de/help/matlab/ref/polyfit.html

Is MATLAB available to you?